# How to set camera for monochrome (black and white) images only?

Tags: android

How to set the camera for only black and white images? In my program I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

for taking images.

Answer (score 11):

The modes like scene modes or the color effects, once the camera interface is open and ready to use. You can use the Camera.Parameters to set the mode once the camera is up. You can use the EFFECT_MONO(monochrome) from the color effects to get black & white images...

The below code snippet shows on how to use it,

```
    mCameraDevPara.setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
    mCameraDev.setParameters(mCameraDevPara);
```

Comment: Actually i am using intent for capturing the image so with that it is not working please tell me with intent ??

Comment: Have you considered converting the image after capture to b&w?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch camera application for taking a shot, there is no way to tell it to shoot in BW mode. 
The MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT and "crop" are only extra parameters which camera application extracts from the launching intent and they are not related to the shooting mode.